# /auth/cognito-idp にリダイレクトするとCSRFエラーになりました。RoRで omniauth-cognito-idp を使っています。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, amazon-cognito

ローカル環境で実装中です。Ruby on Railsでomniauth-cognito-idpを使っています。 `https://localhost:3000/login` から `https://localhost:8081/auth/cognito-idp` にリダイレクトすると、CSRFエラーになりました。

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

SPA構成でSSOする際にCSRF対策をどのようにするのがいいか教えてください。

フロントエンド:React `https://localhost:3000`
バックエンド:Ruby on Rails `https://localhost:8081`
認証プロパイダ：Okta/AWS Cognito

- AWS Cognito/ユーザープール/アプリケーションクライアントの「ホストされたUIを表示」をクリックすると、create_ssoまでコールバックされる、emailなどが取得できることは確認済
- `https://localhost:8081/auth/cognito-idp` リダイレクト
- `http://localhost:8081/api/v1/auth/cognito-idp` ルーティングエラー

Gemfile add

```
gem 'omniauth-cognito-idp'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection'
```

.env add

```
COGNITO_CLIENT_ID=
COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET=
COGNITO_USER_POOL_SITE=
COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID=
```

routes.rb summary

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      post '/sign_in', to: 'sessions#create'
      get '/auth/cognito-idp/callback' => 'sessions#create_sso'
      get '/session_sign_in', to: 'sessions#show'
      get '/sign_out', to: 'sessions#destroy'
    end
  end
end
```

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider(
      :cognito_idp,
      ENV.fetch('COGNITO_CLIENT_ID', nil),
      ENV.fetch('COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET', nil),
      client_options: {
        site: ENV.fetch('COGNITO_USER_POOL_SITE', nil)
      },
      scope: 'email openid',
      user_pool_id: ENV.fetch('COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID', nil),
      aws_region: 'ap-northeast-1',
      callback_path: '/api/v1/auth/cognito-idp/callback'
    )
end
```